# Is it better (for performance/maintainability) to put a conditional within the function or around the function call?

Tags: javascript, function, conditional-statements

If a function depends on the result of a conditional to run, is it better to place that conditional inside the function or around the function call? For example, which of these is better, or what are the benefits of using either?

**Inside**

```
var x = 5,
    preventAlter = false;

function alter() {
    if (!preventAlter) {
        x++;
    }
}

alter();
```

**Outside**

```
var x = 5,
    preventAlter = false;

function alter() {
    x++;
}

if (!preventAlter) {
    alter();
}
```

Comment: Performance should be the last concern here; the real question should be what the responsibility of the function is and how self-contained it should be and how and under what circumstances you want to call it.

Comment: Outside seems faster http://jsperf.com/inside-or-outside999 (inside is 22% slower) but keep in mind that inside is usually used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's neither a question of performance or maintainability, rather it's more around what you want your code to actually do.  Imagine that the scenario is a bit more complex:

```
function counter() {
  this.x = 5;
  this.preventAlter = false;
  this.alter = function() {
    x++;
  }
}
```

Do you want consumers of this object to have to know about the inner workings and know that they have to check the state of `preventAlter` before calling`alter`?

```
var c = new counter();
if (!c.preventAlter)
  c.alter();
```

or is it better for the functionality to be all encapsulated within the object:

```
function counter() {
  this.x = 5;
  this.preventAlter = false;
  this.alter = function() {
    if (!this.preventAlter)
      x++;
  }
}

var c = new counter();
c.alter();
```